# Using reshape or view in a certain fashion

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

```
import torch
import numpy as np
a = torch.tensor([[1, 4], [2, 5],[3, 6]])
bb=a.detach().numpy()
b = a.view(6).detach().numpy()
```

Element `b` is like:

```
[1 4 2 5 3 6]
```

How do I reshape back to the following:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

This is just an example, want some generic answers, even 3D.

Answer (score 1):

In Pytorch you can use reshape and permute as in this example:

```
Import torch
a = torch.randn((3,3,2))
b = a.permute(2,0,1).reshape(-1)
```

```
a
tensor([[[ 0.2372,  0.5550],
         [ 0.7700, -0.3693],
         [-0.4151,  0.6247]],

        [[ 1.2179,  0.6992],
         [ 0.5033,  1.6290],
         [-1.2165, -0.4180]],

        [[ 0.3189,  0.3208],
         [ 0.3894,  2.5544],
         [-1.3069, -0.6905]]])
b
tensor([ 0.2372,  0.7700, -0.4151,  1.2179,  0.5033, -1.2165,  0.3189,  0.3894,
        -1.3069,  0.5550, -0.3693,  0.6247,  0.6992,  1.6290, -0.4180,  0.3208,
         2.5544, -0.6905])
```

I think this solves the problem.

Comment: This one combines each column alternatively, I want to stitch them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remain in PyTorch, you can view `b` in `a`'s shape, then apply a transpose and flatten:

```
>>> b.view(-1,2).T.flatten()
tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

In the 3D case, you can perform similar manipulations using [`torch.transpose`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.transpose.html) which enables you to swap two axes. You get the desired result by combining it with [`torch.view`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.view.html):

- First case (extra dimension last):

  ```
  >>> b = a.view(-1, 1).expand(-1,3).flatten()
  tensor([1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6])

  >>> b.view(-1,2,3).transpose(0,1).flatten()
  tensor([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6])
  ```
- Second case (extra dimension first):

  ```
  >>> b = a.view(1,-1).expand(3,-1).flatten()
  tensor([1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6])

  >>> b.view(3,-1).T.view(-1,2,3).transpose(0,1).flatten()
  tensor([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6])
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help with the `torch` step, but starting with a numpy array:

```
In [70]: a=np.array([[1, 4], [2, 5],[3, 6]])
In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])

In [72]: a.ravel()           # can also use reshape
Out[72]: array([1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6])
```

To get a column major copy:

```
In [73]: a.ravel(order='F')
Out[73]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [74]: a.T.ravel()
Out[74]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```

the transpose:

```
In [79]: a.T
Out[79]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

For 3d arrays, you can use `transpose` with an order parameter.